# Why tableviewcell is returning an optional("")

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to display the result of my request from an api into a cell.I am able to make the request and parse the data. But when I try to display the  content in a cell and print the cell value, the result is optional (“”).Can someone explain me why .

```
cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = apiDataModel.restaurantName
```

`apiDataModel.restaurantName` is not `nil`

Any help is appreciated ! Thanks

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DiscoverTableViewCell

    cell.discoverImage.image = UIImage(named: "Detail")
    cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = apiDataModel.restaurantName


    return cell
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! DiscoverTableViewCell
         print(currentCell.restaurantNameLabel.text)


}

func search(url: String, parameters : [String:String]) {
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(apiKey)"]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: headers ) .responseJSON{
        URLResponse in
        //print(URLResponse)
        if URLResponse.result.isSuccess {
            let yelpDataJSON = JSON(URLResponse.value!)
            self.updateYelpData(Json: yelpDataJSON)
            print("\(yelpDataJSON)")
        }else{
            print("error")
        }

    }
}

func updateYelpData(Json : JSON){

   if  let nameJSON = Json["businesses"][0]["name"].string {

   apiDataModel.restaurantName = nameJSON
    print(apiDataModel.restaurantName)
    apiDataModel.restaurantLocation = Json["businesses"][0]["location"]["display_address"][0].stringValue


    }else{
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I used it for diagnostic purposes . I could not understand why my label could not display the result etc... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You’re not showing us where you called `search`, but `request` is an asynchronous method, but you never call `reloadData` on your table view inside `updateYelpData`. Thus the initial population of the table view is happening before the data has been retrieved and parsed by Alamofire.

If you put a `tableView.reloadData()` inside `updateYelpData`, the table view will be update with real data after it is retrieved by Alamofire.

Comment: asynchronous tasks are always a matter of miss for newbies

Comment: Yes, that’s why I pointed it out to Vangola, as it’s the root of the problem here.

Comment: Thank you . It's working . I did not know that I had to call tableView.reloadData() . Thank you . Need to learn about asynchronous method .

Answer (score 1):

It appears `apiDataModel.restaurantName` is `nil` / `""` and setting that to the label text will make it `""`

You need to reload the table after

```
self.updateYelpData(Json: yelpDataJSON)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

and make sure you have a valid result

Comment: Thank you . It's working . I did not know that I had to call tableView.reloadData() .